# Key Error when passing list of input in .predict() using Pipeline

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, pipeline

From what I found out when trying myself and reading here on stackoverflow, When I pass a pandas dataframe to .predict(), it successfully gives me a prediction value. Like below:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('OneHotEncoder', encoder), ('RobustScaler', scaler),('RandomForestRegressor',RFregsr)])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
with open('trained_RFregsr.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(pipe, f)
test = pipe.predict(X[0:1])
print(test)

>> [10.82638889]
```

But when I try to pass in a list of all input values required, 25 in my case, it returns a key error. This is related to how pandas dataframe only returns column names when iterated, and not the values.

```
test = pipe.predict([['M', 15, 'U', 'LE3', 'T', 4, 3, 'teacher', 'services', 1, 3, 0,
        'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 5, 4, 4, 2, 15, 16]])
print(test)
>> KeyError : 'sex'
```

I have trained a model using 25 values consisting of categoricals and numerical values to predict a single int value. As to why I am pickle-ing the file, I have to deploy it using FastAPI and it has to receive input from API endpoints. If required I can post complete code somewhere.
Please tell me how I can safely pass a list of required inputs so that the model can predict on them?

EDIT: This is how I have used the OneHotEncoder:

```
import category_encoders as ce
encoder = ce.OneHotEncoder()

x_train = encoder.fit_transform(X_train)

x_test = encoder.transform(X_test)
```

Comment: Was the pipeline fit with a pandas DataFrames?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes Yes. X_train and y_train are pandas dataframes. Is there another way?

Comment: Please always provide the full error traceback. And your edit with the one-hot encoding seems to contradict the inclusion of that encoder in the pipeline?

Comment: @BenReiniger The part in my EDIT was done before initializing Pipeline. I provided the exact error being occurred and not the full traceback as it was longer than the post itself. AlexanderL.Hayes picked up on it correctly. It was my encoder expecting a pandas DataFrame and not a list.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes's answer presents a different error than you've reported, and produces it with a column transformer, which you haven't used (as far as you've said). sklearn should throw warnings but not errors when predicting on a non-frame input, except as in the answer (column transformer with affected columns given by name). Since your first encoder is not from sklearn, it probably is the case that a frame is assumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an error where `encoder` is a `ColumnTransformer` expecting a `pandas` dataframe. `pipe.predict` is looking for a column named `sex`, but not finding one.

For example, this:

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "zero":  ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"],
    "one":   [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    "two":   [0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 0.7],
    "label": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]})

encoder = ColumnTransformer(
    [('ohe', OneHotEncoder(), ["zero", "one"])], remainder="passthrough")

X, y = df.drop(["label"], axis=1), df["label"]

pipe = Pipeline([('ohe', encoder), ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())])
pipe.fit(X, y)
pipe.predict([["A", 1, 0.5]])
```

Results in (`scikit-learn==1.2.0`):

```
ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```

But switching to:

```py
X_test = pd.DataFrame([["A", 1, 0.5]], columns=["zero", "one", "two"])
print(pipe.predict(X_test))
# [0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Converting the list to a DataFrame first before passing it solved the issue.